# Android 4.0 Login and Registration using JSON

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I'm trying to do login and regitration on an Android 4.0 device.  So I had to update my code to use Asynctask and I'm getting errors and not sure how to fix them.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

//JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            new RegisterTask().execute();
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
}

class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
int success;
String email;
String password;
String name;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
    password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
    name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
    JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

    Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

    try {
        int success = json.getInt(KEY_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            // DATABASE HANDLER
            // user successfully logged in
            // Store user details in SQLite Database
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                    getApplicationContext());
            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

            // Clear all previous data in database
            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());

            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME),
                    json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),
                    json_user.getString(KEY_UID),
                    json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
if (success == 1) {
        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(dashboard);
        finish();
}else{
    //tvLError.setText("Incorrect username/password");

 }
}
}
}
```

And the error log I am getting...

12-02 20:45:23.140: E/JSON Parser(28208): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

```
<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
12-02 20:45:23.140: W/dalvikvm(28208): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415e62a0)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): at com.example.cs309.gotoclass.RegisterActivity$RegisterTask.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:89)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): at com.example.cs309.gotoclass.RegisterActivity$RegisterTask.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:1)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): ... 5 more
```

registerUser

```
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}
```

Comment: post more logs and full stacktrace

Comment: Updated question with registerUser

Comment: you have issue with json parsing so if you post json string retrieved from server then this will help more for solving your issue

Comment: `(RegisterActivity.java:89)` there is a null value. What is in there?

Comment: I'm confused on how to get the json string

Comment: Are you sure your Internet is on? Wifi? Are you sure you have all the permissions in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @user1869161 : just paste your web url in web browser or you can also put an System.out.println(result); inside getJSONFromUrl method to print string returned from server

Comment: @Sohel Mansuri : Yes, it has internet permission and wifi connection

Comment: @imran khan : so just go to the web address of the php files that are used to connect to the DB?

Comment: @user1869161 : yes and add all parameter with url  and easy way is just put System.out.println(result);  in getJSONFromUrl after where you are getting string from server and save logcat to file and extract json string

Answer (score 0):

make sure to validate you login details for null values & then only call AsychTask & call registerUser() method.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to figure out without prper source code. But check Line#89 in RegisterActivity.java which is getting called from doInBackground(). Put a break point and check which item is coming as NULL (because of that you are getting NullPointerException). Once you fix that it will work.